# rsync command to delete a directory on a remote system

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rsync

There is a remote system where i have read/write permissions only in one directoty. I use it to store the results of the nightly builds.

For uploading the results for a specific day, i do an `rsync` of `<date_dir>` on the remote directory using following command:

`rsync -zavR <date_dir> <server_name>:/path/of/the/directory/where/i/have/permission/`

Now, sometimes i need to delete the `<date_dir>` directory at destination. For this, I tried following command:

`rsync -avh <date_dir> <server_name>:/path/of/the/directory/where/i/have/permission/ --delete`

This command deletes the contents of `<date_dir>` at destination but the directory `<date_dir>` itself is not deleted.

I also tried to give `--force-delete` in rsync command, but it gives following error on my system:

`rsync: --force-delete: unknown option`

What can be the command to delete the `<date_dir>` directory on the remote server using `rsync`.

PS: I tried setting up password-less authentication using `SSH` but i don't have permissions to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the very directory you are going to copy, `rsync` won't delete it. `--delete` means to remove a directory or file which does not exist on the senders side.  Obviously, `date_dir` exists on your local machine (otherwise rsync would complain about copying a non-existent directory). If you want to keep your local directory and only delete the remove copy, `rsync` is not the right tool, but you could use `rsh ..... rm -r` to remove the directory on the remote side.

Comment: I've already explored `sshpass` but its not available on my system and i dont have admin privileges to install it either. However, i will check if `rsh` is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more idea - I don't know whether it will work: `rsync --exclude date_dir --delete-excluded date_dir .....`

Comment: @Yash : Read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access) for a discussion on how to install Apt packages without root rights.

Comment: I have fedora not ubuntu :(

Answer (score 1):

If you can execute a remote `rm` command that is almost certainly safest. But there may be situations where you don't have direct shell access to the remote side, for example when the ssh key you are using is only allowed to run a restricted set of commands in authorized_keys and `rm` is not one of them.

You can accomplish the task with rsync alone as shown below, but you should ***test carefully*** and be extra sure of your inputs:

```
rsync -avh -n --delete \
  --filter="+ <date_dir>/**" \
  --filter="+ <date_dir>" \
  --filter="- *" \
  /path/to/empty/ <server_name>:/path/of/the/directory/where/i/have/permission/
```

The idea is to synchronize an EMPTY directory at `/path/to/empty` with the remote directory that you have permission to modify. Without filters, of course, that would just delete ***EVERYTHING*** in the remote directory.

So we use the fact that rsync applies filters in order, using the first matching rule. The first filter deletes the contents of `<date_dir>`, the second filter deletes `<date_dir>` itself, and the last filter saves us from deleting the rest of the directory's contents.

I've added a `-n` dry run flag just in case someone isn't paying close attention and pastes this command. Remove it to run the command for real.

Comment: I am getting a `cannot delete non-empty directory: ...` on this. Works on empty ones though, so currently my best here, is a two step approach: first run the empty directory against the subdir (without any filter) and then against the upper dir, with the mentioned filter....

Comment: I have seen the same error mentioned by @informatik-handwerk.de - it's cool that we have a solution but this is also very unnatural to use.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

In the given context following command works for me:

`rsh <server_name> "rm -rf /path/of/the/directory/where/i/have/permission/<date_dir>"`